# how to get the uncommon data in two queries in for the same table in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have three mysql tables as follows

### msg_table

```
msg_id  | msg_to | msg_from |msg

1 | 55 | 54 | hello

2 |55 |45 |Nice

3 |16 |55 |world

4 |54 |55 |Nice job
```

What i need to get is

get the **msg_from** ids Which is **msg_to='55'** and **msg_to** ids which is **msg_from='55'** and join these together and get the distinct values out of that.

So as for the example it should return

54,45,16

Is this possible? or do i have to follow any other rule to accomplish this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNION`(implicit distinct):

```
SELECT msg_from AS id FROM msg_table WHERE msg_to   = 55
UNION 
SELECT msg_to         FROM msg_table WHERE msg_from = 55;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/163837/1)

This will give you:

```
| ID |
------
| 54 |
| 45 |
| 16 |
```

Comment: OMG it works... I tried lots of time with UNION.But no luck. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `UNION` to combine the result from the queries which only gives unique `ID`.

```
SELECT  msg_to to_from FROM msg_Table WHERE msg_from = 55
UNION
SELECT  msg_from to_from FROM msg_Table WHERE msg_to = 55
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/163837/3)

OUTPUT

```
╔═════════╗
║ TO_FROM ║
╠═════════╣
║      16 ║
║      54 ║
║      45 ║
╚═════════╝
```